# Visualizing data in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

C#: visualizing data on datagridview. Please take a look on my attachment for the problem. I need an understading on encapsulation and constructor overloading. I can do this without following instruction. All I want to know is how to do this with following instruction. Can someone explain me this. Thank you.    [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ujyB.jpg)

Comment: Probably not the right Site to ask for tutorials